# How to make a header change it's size proportionally to how much text is in it?

Tags: css

I haven't touched HTML and CSS in a long time, But I am making a calculator on Electron.

If you put too many numbers in, The calculation will not fit the fixed width and you won't see it completely.

Using `vm`, `em` or `max-width: 100%` does not work.

This is what the calculator looks like if too many numbers are in:

[image]

This is the code for the specific header that displays the numbers:

```css
#calculation {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please upload what it looks right now, your current code creating the problem, a bit more description of what you want it to be, maybe a mock-up, etc?

Comment: Is the requirement to alter the font size so that the long number always fits in? You'll need javascript if so.

Comment: Potential to use experimental CSS property text-size-adjust depending on the browser compatibility and accessibility of the project.

Comment: @AHaworth I am not on my device that I use to code at the moment, Can you please refer to me to how it’s done?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML. e.g. is it an input and if so of what type and are you using monospace fonts?

Comment: @AHaworth It’s just a header, I use the buttons to append numbers into it using querySelector in a script element in the HTML itself.

Comment: OK, it's that JS that will be useful as it means you are checking on every character. Please could you put that JS into your question (as code, not an image).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getBoundingClientRect().width` to get the width of an element and `window.getComputedStyle(...).getPropertyValue(...))` to get the font size of an element. Than you could decrement the font size in a while loop until the width of the content fits its container.

**Working example:**

```js
const test_header = document.querySelector('#test');
const test_content = document.querySelector('#test span');
const header_width = parseInt(test_header.getBoundingClientRect().width);
let content_font_size = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(test_content, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

while (test_content.getBoundingClientRect().width > header_width) {
  content_font_size -= 1;
  test_content.style.fontSize = content_font_size + 'px';
}
```

```css
#test-wrapper header {
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="test-wrapper">
  <p>with static font-size:</p>
  
  <header>
    <span>0123456789</span>
  </header>
  
  <hr>
  <p>with dynamic font-size:</p>
  
  <header id="test">
    <span>0123456789</span>
  </header>
</div>
```